# Should the Use Case be responsible for transforming its primitive parameters into typed data for the Entity to use?

Tags: domain-driven-design, use-case, clean-architecture, dto

I'm building a Use Case for creating blog posts, this Use Case has its own "DTO", which is basically a parameter object with only primitive data, as follows:

**Use Case's DTO (Parameter Object):**

```
export class CreatePostInput {
  public id: string;
  public slug: string;
  public title: string;
  public authorId: string;
  public platform: string;
  public tags: string[];
  public images: string[];
  public content: string;
  public createdAt: string;
}
```

inside my Use Case, I have to create an entity that is built with most of the data of the Use Case's DTO, the "problem" is that most of the entity's properties are typed with Value Object's, for example:

**Post Entity**

```
export class Post {
    private id: PostId;
    private slug: Slug;
    private title: Title;
    private authorId: AuthorId;
    private platform: Platform;
    private tags: Tag[];
    private images: Image[];
    private content: string;
    private createdAt: Date;
}
```

**Use Case:**

```
export class CreatePost {

  public async create(CreatePostInput: CreatePostInput): Promise<CreatePostOutput> {

    if (CreatePostInput.images.length > 0) {
      // do something...
    }

    // some more logic using typed data

    const PostEntity = new Post(CreatePostInput);
    // ...
    // return CreatePostOutput
  }

}
```

1. Should the Use Case be responsible for creating the entity's Value Objects or transforming its primitive data into something else? if so, is there a problem with instantiating the Value Objects inside the Use Case?
2. If I happen to have more entities and more Value Objects in this use case, how should i organize all this creation? builder pattern?

Comment: Is this some completely new meaning of "Use Case" that I'm not aware of?

Comment: sorry, i do not follow?

Comment: To me, a Use Case is a text document, containing a written description of how a user would interact with the system being designed, in order to achieve a specific goal.  A bit like a User Story, but much more detailed.  Use Cases are written before you've written any code, as they are part of the requirement analysis phase.  What you're describing here is nothing like that.

Comment: i'm sorry, is that because i over-simplified my example? sure, it could be more complex if you will, but I'm talking about the concept of "Use Case" of Uncle Bob's book "Clean Architecture"

Comment: quoting a piece of his article "...These use cases orchestrate the flow of data to and from the entities, and direct those entities to use their enterprise wide business rules to achieve the goals of the use case."

https://blog.cleancoder.com/uncle-bob/2012/08/13/the-clean-architecture.html

Comment: To me, he is mixing up the use case - a written description of how a user interacts with the system - with the business logic that implements that use case.

Comment: @SimonB he isn't mixing it up. The idea behind it is, that you have functionalities that your code implements - use cases. So if the use case is the thing that have to be implemented, why not give them a class which implements it. From my understanding Bob views a use case as normal flow and exceptional flows, stripping all the overhead of the traditional use case that has all sorts of additional information.

Comment: @SimonB: Public application service methods are sometimes defined as use cases due to their tendency to map one to one. If it helps, think of use cases as either a public application service method (or a command/query if you're using something like mediator in your application layer)

Answer (score 1):

First, allow me to distinguish client request from use-case input which is considered to be a boundary object. The former by nature consists of primitives (you called it "input" in your example) while the latter is only required if you choose to reflect client request as a set of value objects (at least for some client properties).

How to create an entity out of an input object (be it client request or boundary object) - that should be achieved using a factory or, for a simple entity, directly through entity's constructor. Either way, I find it more appropriate to have input's properties (those relevant to the entity) passed to the factory/constructor, rather than pass input object as a whole.

I would recommend to transform client request into input object. Should this transformation take place in UI layer (e.g. web api) or inside use-case? I personally prefer the UI layer, in order to increase isolation level of application layer, that is make it more technology-ignorant, more domain-focused.

As for massive creation of entities and values objects, it is possible to use builder pattern in some cases, especially for complex value objects (plenty of articles on web). It is also OK to use good old methods to update an entity (and of course apply necessary validations/rules inside those methods).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, the use case should just delegate the calls to other objects, that should be responsible for things. Move your creation of the object into a separate factory method - your use case should look something like this:

```
export class Post {
  // ...

  public static fromInput(input: CreatePostInput): Post {
    // creation logic here
  }
}

export class CreatePost {

  public async create(createPostInput: CreatePostInput): Promise<CreatePostOutput> {
    const PostEntity = Post.fromInput(createPostInput);
    // ...
    // return createPostOutput
  }
}
```

Comment: I see, but in that case, my Post entity is tight couple to the CreatePostInput, which I don't think is a good thing for my entity to know about, what if I have different use cases?

Comment: It isn't, because factory method is responsible for converting CreatePostInput into a Post entity. fromInput is a static method. It is the equivalent of PostFactory.fromInput()

Comment: i see, does it belongs to the use case's layer or the entity's? because let's say the CreatePostInput has information for others Entities that I'm going to use in the same use case, should I have a factory for each entity in the use case layer?

Comment: @Thiago What you should do is create the parameters on the use case that you want to receive. You then create a factory for each entity yes. I think you have a problem with thinking about the layers. The use case is an entry point into your domain layer. There is only one layer, that is split into different domains. Basically all the factories, use cases, entities live in the same layer, but different domain (like sales, warehouse, etc).

Comment: The DTO lives on the API layer, so the parameter of the use case should not be a DTO, but some object that you define when creating the use case (your domain layer should not know about the outside layers). You can indeed then use the same object in the API layer as a DTO, but that is incidental. I hope I'm clear enough in what I am trying to say.

Comment: thanks, I understand it, I just called it "DTO" for explaining purposes, CreatePostInput is an object parameter for the Use Case. I like the approach towards a PostFactory or PostBuilder but not all in the same file/entity, do you think is a good approach if a have factories/builders for each use case, separated files -- (i know this is just a detail)

Comment: It is fine, as long as you have them "near" the things that you build with them. Basically just don't have a folder named builders at root level, but have them in the same folder as Post entity for example, and you should be good.

Comment: thanks for the answer, one last thing i forgot, how would you use/inject this in the Use Case? because I cannot test a static method, how to solve this? make the factory into a real instance?

Comment: I think you can test this code just fine. You can also test fromInput() separately if you wanted. What would be the gain of having the factory as a dependency?

Comment: hmm, that way I could mock the factory dependency and control the behavior of the Entity, but if I hard-coded it I'll lose that.

Comment: Technically yes, make a factory and then use it instead of a static method. Just know that if you mock the factory, whenever the factory changes, mocks will become lies :) But that is probably just my distaste for mocking speaking :D

Comment: got it, thanks! i know this is a subjective thing, but why you "distaste" mocking?

Comment: Because it makes your tests highly coupled to implementation. Once you change the implementation you have to change all the places that you mocked.  Imagine having a function that is called from 5 other functions. Let's say that you have only 20 tests total. When this function changes you will not only have to modify the tests for this function, but also 20 other tests, that are green at the moment. The question is: will you remember all the places? With mocking green tests basically don't tell you how the change affected the actual behavior of the system.

Answer (score -1):

Someone has to convert for example a string containing an id into a PostId, and s complete CreatePostInput into a PostEntity. The question is: Who does it? Obviously either the code calling your “use case”, or the use case itself, or whatever code your “use case” calls.

Your caller would likely know a CreatePostInput and can create one and fill it in, but it knows nothing about a PostInput and shouldn’t, so it cannot do the conversion. The code called by your use case would likely know a PostEntity but not a CreatePostInput, and it shouldn’t, so it cannot do the conversion either.

Either CreatePostEntity or PostEntity would have code for the conversion. I would assume that PostEntity would be at a lower level and more stable, so I would put the conversion into CreatePostInput (but that’s up to you). And it is all called by your use case.